# How update table column using row number

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, row-number

Hi I have a table `#Configuration` and if exist any record  where `Schedule =N'Test'` and `Sequence >=2000000` and `Kind <> 632`  then I want update Sequence on this and other records in schedule test where Kind <>632. Sequence should start from 10 and next schould be +10 but i want the same order which is now
 So I have to update record with [ConfigurationId] = 8 and set Sequence new seqeunce  for all records in schedule test where Kind <> 632

I know that i have to use `rownumber()` but i don't know how.

```
if object_id(N'tempdb..#Configuration') is not null
drop table #Configuration;

create table #Configuration
(
    [ConfigurationId] int
    ,Kind int 
    ,Schedule nvarchar(100)
    ,[Sequence] int 
);

insert into #Configuration
Values ( 1,15,N'I',10)
,( 300,16,N'I',20)
,( 248,817,N'Test',3000)
 ,( 675,817,N'Test',20)    
 ,( 432,632,N'Test',2000000)  
 ,( 889,632,N'Test',2000010)  
 ,( 1,632,N'Test',2000020)  
 ,( 8,999,N'Test',2000030)  
  ,( 44453,632,N'Test',2000040)  

  select * from #Configuration
```

Comment: Please post the expected results. Also why you want to check _Schedule =N'Test' and Sequence >=2000000 and Kind <> 632_ and then update just where _Kind <> 632_?

Comment: Not entirely sure i understand your requirement.  Is the above your expected results, or your sample data; if the latter what are your expected results. What have you tried to solve this problem yourself?

Comment: You are on the right track with using row_number. Please post your attempt along with a sample output. Row_number() over (partition by.....order by...)*10 or something like that.

Comment: What do you mean by +10? the actual value +10 or you want (10, 20, 30 ...etc)?

Comment: bad english. your explanation is not very clear. I can understand how the table is, but I am confused as to why you need row number.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `ROW_NUMBER` in update statement directly, so you need to wrap a `SELECT` statement in a derived table or common table expression. To preserve the existing order, specify `ORDER BY [Sequence]` in the `OVER` clause. Also, filter out the rows, which values you want to be preserved (i.e. add `WHERE Kind <> 632 and Schedule = 'Test'`). Since you want sequence with gaps (10, 20, 30 instead of 1, 2, 3), simply multiply the generated row number by 10. And after that, use this `SELECT` statement to update your temp table, like this:

```
;with cte as (
    select c.ConfigurationId, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY [Sequence]) * 10 as NewSequence
    from #Configuration c
    where c.Kind <> 632 and c.Schedule = 'Test'
)
update #Configuration set
    [Sequence] = cte.NewSequence
from cte
where #Configuration.ConfigurationId = cte.ConfigurationId

select * from #Configuration
```